# Webclient webflux "java.lang.IllegalStateException" when I try to map in an object an error that is returned by the API I am calling

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, java-17

Java 17 and last version of webflux

I have the following webclient configuration class where I am mapped the APIs errors to custom exceptions in the static method **higyrusErrorHandler**, then this method is added like a exchange filter function when I define the bean **webClientHygirusApi**:

```
@Configuration
public class WebClientConfiguration implements PathAndParamName{

    @Value("${api.higyrus.protocol}")
    private String higyrusApiProtocol;

    @Value("${api.higyrus.host}")
    private String higyrusApiHost;

    @Value("${api.higyrus.port}")
    private String higyrusApiPort;

    

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebClientConfiguration.class);

    private static void logMethodAndUrl(ClientRequest request) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(request.method().name())
          .append(" to ")
          .append(request.url());
        logger.debug(sb.toString());
    }

    private static void logHeaders(ClientRequest request) {
        request.headers().forEach((name, values) -> {
            values.forEach(value -> {
                logNameAndValuePair(name, value);
            });
        });
    }

    private static void logNameAndValuePair(String name, String value) {
        logger.debug("{}={}", name, value);
    }

    /*
     * higyrusErrorHandler
     */
    public static ExchangeFilterFunction higyrusErrorHandler() {
        return ExchangeFilterFunction.ofResponseProcessor(clientResponse -> {
            if (clientResponse.statusCode().isError()) {
                return clientResponse.bodyToMono(ErrorResponse.class)
                        .flatMap(errorResponse -> {
                            if (errorResponse != null && errorResponse.getErrors() != null && !errorResponse.getErrors().isEmpty()) {
                                // Manejar el error personalizado según la lógica de tu aplicación
                                ErrorDetails errorDetails = errorResponse.getErrors().get(0);
                                return Mono.<ClientResponse>error(new HigyrusApiException(errorDetails.getTitle(), errorDetails.getDetail()));
                            } else {
                                // Manejar otros errores no personalizados aquí si es necesario
                                return Mono.<ClientResponse>error(new Exception("Error de servidor no manejado"));
                            }
                        });
            } else if (clientResponse.statusCode().value() == HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value()) {
                return Mono.error(new BadCredentialsException("Invalid credentials"));
            } else if (clientResponse.statusCode().value() == HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN.value()) {
                return Mono.error(new NotAuthorizedException("Not authorized to call api"));
            } else if (clientResponse.statusCode().is5xxServerError()) {
                return Mono.error(new Exception("Server error"));
            } else if (clientResponse.statusCode().is4xxClientError()) {
                return Mono.error(new Exception("Client error"));
            } else {
                return Mono.just(clientResponse);
            }
        });
    }
    

    /**
     * logResponse
     * @return
     */
    public static ExchangeFilterFunction logResponse() {
        return ExchangeFilterFunction.ofResponseProcessor(clientResponse -> {
            HttpStatusCode status = clientResponse.statusCode();
            logger.debug("Returned staus code {} ({})", status.value(), status.toString());
            if (clientResponse.statusCode() != null && (clientResponse.statusCode().is4xxClientError()
                    || clientResponse.statusCode().is5xxServerError())) {
                return clientResponse.bodyToMono(String.class)
                        .flatMap(body -> {
                            logger.debug("Body is {}", body);
                            return Mono.just(clientResponse);
                        });
            } else {
                return Mono.just(clientResponse);
            }
          });
    }

    /**
     * logRequest
     * @return
     */
    public static ExchangeFilterFunction logRequest() {
        return ExchangeFilterFunction.ofRequestProcessor(request -> {
            logMethodAndUrl(request);
            logHeaders(request);
            return Mono.just(request);
        });
    }

    /**
     * webClient para Higyrus Api
     * @return
     */
  @Bean
  public WebClient webClientHygirusApi() {
      //uncomment if you need log request and response body
      HttpClient httpClient =
                HttpClient.create()
                    .wiretap(
                       this.getClass().getCanonicalName(), LogLevel.INFO, AdvancedByteBufFormat.TEXTUAL);
   return WebClient.builder()
                .baseUrl(String.format(HS_MAIN_PATH, higyrusApiProtocol,
                        higyrusApiHost,
                        higyrusApiPort))
                .filters(exchangeFilterFunctions -> {
                      exchangeFilterFunctions.add(higyrusErrorHandler());
                      exchangeFilterFunctions.add(logRequest());
                      exchangeFilterFunctions.add(logResponse());
                 })
                .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
                .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .exchangeStrategies(ExchangeStrategies
                        .builder()
                        .codecs(codecs -> codecs
                              .defaultCodecs()
                              .maxInMemorySize(-1))
                        .build())
                .build();
  }
  
}
```

The service class have a void mehod called **changeUserPassword** that use the **WebClientCofiguration** class defined above:

@Service
public class HigyrusService implements PathAndParamName{

```
@Autowired
private WebClientConfiguration webClientConfiguration;

/**
 * changeUserPassword
 * @param user
 * @return
 */
public void changeUserPassword(final ChangePassword dataPassChange  ) {
    
    HigyrusToken token = this.getToken(dataPassChange.getUser());
    
    Map<String, String> bodyMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    bodyMap.put(HS_USERNAME, dataPassChange.getUser());
    bodyMap.put(HS_PASSWORD, dataPassChange.getCurrentPassword());
    bodyMap.put(HS_NEW_PASSWORD, dataPassChange.getNewPassword());
    bodyMap.put(HS_REAL_NAME, dataPassChange.getRealName());
    bodyMap.put(HS_EMAIL, dataPassChange.getEmail());
    
    webClientConfiguration.webClientHygirusApi()
            .post()
              .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
                      .path(String.format(HS_POST_CHANGE_USER_PASS, dataPassChange.getUser()))
                        .build())
            .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(bodyMap))
            .headers(h -> h.setBearerAuth(token.getToken()))
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class)
            .block();
}
```

}

In case a handled error occurs in the API I'm consuming with the web client, the API returns the following json structure:

```
{
   "errors":[
      {
         "title":"title",
         "detail":"detail"
      }
   ],
   "timestamp":"06/12/2023 12:04:08"
}
```

The problem I'm having is that when an error occurs in the API I'm calling with the web client, said error is not mapped to a custom exception **HigyrusApiException**, despite the logic of method **higyrusErrorHandler()**:

```
if (clientResponse.statusCode().isError()) {
    return clientResponse.bodyToMono(ErrorResponse.class)
            .flatMap(errorResponse -> {
                if (errorResponse != null && errorResponse.getErrors() != null && !errorResponse.getErrors().isEmpty()) {
                    // Manejar el error personalizado según la lógica de tu aplicación
                    ErrorDetails errorDetails = errorResponse.getErrors().get(0);
                    return Mono.<ClientResponse>error(new HigyrusApiException(errorDetails.getTitle(), errorDetails.getDetail()));
                } else {
                    // Manejar otros errores no personalizados aquí si es necesario
                    return Mono.<ClientResponse>error(new Exception("Error de servidor no manejado"));
                }
            });
}
```

And I get the following **ERROR**:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: The underlying HTTP client completed without emitting a response